# get textNode with division from div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, division, textnode

```
<div class="list" data-id="1">One</div>
<div class="list" data-id="2">Two</div>
<div class="list" data-id="3">Three</div>
<div class="list" data-id="4">Four</div>
```

---

```
var text = $(".list").contents().filter(function() {
return this.nodeType == 3; }).text()
alert(text);
```

Now, I get alert "OneTwoThreeFour"

But, I want to get "One|Two|Three|Four" like this ....using "|" division

Please help me.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) after [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

> *The `join()` method joins all elements of an array into a string.*
>   
>   *`jQuery.map()` translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.*

```js
var text = $(".list").map(function() {
  return this.textContent;
}).get();

alert(text.join('|'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list" data-id="1">One</div>
<div class="list" data-id="2">Two</div>
<div class="list" data-id="3">Three</div>
<div class="list" data-id="4">Four</div>
```

*Or using your approach*

```js
var text = $(".list").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).get();
text = text.map(function(t) { //.map as text is a collection of `TextNode` objects
  return t.textContent;
});
alert(text.join('|'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list" data-id="1">One</div>
<div class="list" data-id="2">Two</div>
<div class="list" data-id="3">Three</div>
<div class="list" data-id="4">Four</div>
```